# php how to get web image size in kb?

Tags: php, image, image-size

php how to get web image size in kb?

`getimagesize` only get the width and height.

and `filesize` caused `waring`.

```
$imgsize=filesize("http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2564.jpg");
echo $imgsize;
```

`Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2564.jpg`

Is there any other way to get a web image size in kb?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Remote file size without downloading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Comment: This seems to be related : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145021/php-getimagesize-alternatives-without-javascript[/link]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Short of doing a complete HTTP request, there is no easy way:

```
$img = get_headers("http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2564.jpg", 1);
print $img["Content-Length"];
```

You can likely utilize [`cURL`](http://php.net/cURL) however to send a [lighter `HEAD` request instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378915/header-only-retreival-in-php-via-curl).

Comment: great, get_headers run faster. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your HTTP client is not sending any headers saying it accepts gzipped HTTP responses, or else the `Content-Length` will be wrong because the server will send compressed data back.

Comment: @Darien: Excellent catch! Luckily `get_headers` sends a pretty plain HTTP/1.0 request. But for cURL this would need more diligence.

Comment: `get_headers` can also do a HEAD request. there is an example in the php manual showing how.

Comment: This sometimes returns an array: `Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 103823
)` How do I handle that? `get_headers($imageURL, 1)["Content-Length"]` where `$imageURL` is https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/23/bb/f3/23bbf35e95d5ad470b038d420fc1a9c4.jpg

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
$file_size = filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Advertisers/2564.jpg"); // Get file size in bytes
$file_size = $file_size / 1024; // Get file size in KB
echo $file_size; // Echo file size
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about using `filesize()` for remote files, but there are good snippets on php.net though about using cURL.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a permissions issue because filesize() should work just fine.

Here is an example:

```
php > echo filesize("./9832712.jpg");
1433719
```

Make sure the permissions are set correctly on the image and that the path is also correct. You will need to apply some math to convert from bytes to KB but after doing that you should be in good shape!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link regarding filesize()

You cannot use filesize() to retrieve remote file information.  It must first be downloaded or determined by another method

Using Curl here is a good method:

[Tutorial](http://www.learnxpress.com/get-files-from-remote-file-size-with-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also this function

```
<?php
$filesize=file_get_size($dir.'/'.$ff);
$filesize=$filesize/1024;// to convert in KB
echo $filesize;


function file_get_size($file) {
    //open file
    $fh = fopen($file, "r");
    //declare some variables
    $size = "0";
    $char = "";
    //set file pointer to 0; I'm a little bit paranoid, you can remove this
    fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //set multiplicator to zero
    $count = 0;
    while (true) {
        //jump 1 MB forward in file
        fseek($fh, 1048576, SEEK_CUR);
        //check if we actually left the file
        if (($char = fgetc($fh)) !== false) {
            //if not, go on
            $count ++;
        } else {
            //else jump back where we were before leaving and exit loop
            fseek($fh, -1048576, SEEK_CUR);
            break;
        }
    }
    //we could make $count jumps, so the file is at least $count * 1.000001 MB large
    //1048577 because we jump 1 MB and fgetc goes 1 B forward too
    $size = bcmul("1048577", $count);
    //now count the last few bytes; they're always less than 1048576 so it's quite fast
    $fine = 0;
    while(false !== ($char = fgetc($fh))) {
        $fine ++;
    }
    //and add them
    $size = bcadd($size, $fine);
    fclose($fh);
    return $size;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size by using the get_headers() function. Use below code:

```
    $image = get_headers($url, 1);
    $bytes = $image["Content-Length"];
    $mb = $bytes/(1024 * 1024);
    echo number_format($mb,2) . " MB";
```